# GIT/ Bash Script

Tags: bash, git

Adding all file under directory. For Ex there are 4 file under dir called test and I want to add them using git add command.

`$DIR` is `/USER/NAME/test`
Currently using git add "`DIR`"
and its adding files in `PWD` instead of adding file in `testfolder`

Answer (score 0):

If your repo (the folder which includes a .git/ subfolder is somewhere else), make sure your script specify where is that .git folder:

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/my/repo/.git --work-tree=$DIR add .
```